# Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, swift3

I working on a project that is written in `swift 3.0`. My requirement is to save data that i enter on some text fields and populate one of those attributes in to a table view, and once a row is selected I wants to update that records (re-assign values on my text fields).

However im having an issue with my code when i try to fetch data that i have saved in **`core data`** and assigning them in to an array. Basically I have an entity named "**Task**" and it got three attributes, and since i wants to populate one of those attributes(called "name") that i have saved on core data, to a table view i have written the code as follow. But im getting an exception in the following line in my code saying "`Could not cast value of type NSTaggedPointerString (0x10d8f7b90) to NSArray (0x10d8f7c58)`".

**The error line and the code as bellow.**

```
 tasks += expName as! [Task]
```

**Here is my full code:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

var tasks = [Task] ()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    //var error : NSError?
    let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName: "Task")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false 
    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        // check data existance
        if results.count>0 {
            print(results.count)

            for resultGot in results as! [NSManagedObject]{

                if let expName = resultGot.value(forKey:"name"){
                    print("expence name is :", expName)
                    tasks += expName as! [Task]      
                    print("my array is : \(tasks)")
                }
            }    
        }    
    }catch{  
        print("No Data to load")
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = tasks [indexPath.row] as? String
    return cell
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tasks.count
 }

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowEditTask"{
     let v = segue.destination as! ViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let row = indexPath?.row


    }
 }
```

Comment: You should post only codes that are related to the problem. Otherwise, it takes time for reader to find out the problem. For example `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and `viewDidLoad` don't lead to the problem. Then, if possible, indicate the line of code that throw the exception. You will have more chance to get help!

Comment: Sir i have clearly indicated the line that i have the issue underneath my description.

Comment: `results` is an array of tasks, `resultGot` is a task in that array, `expName` is    a value for key `name`. What is it's type in core data model? String I suppose? Why then are you trying to cast it to an array of Tasks?

Comment: Im very much new to swift, yes the type of the data model is String, basically I want the "name" to get populate in my table view. if I try to write the code as 
tasks += expName
it gives me an error message saying it cannot convert like that to an expected argument. I want my expName to assign in to task array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that `NSTaggedPointerString` (`expName`) can not be cast to `NSArray` (`[Task]`)

Your goal is to add all `Task`s to the task array if the `name` property is not `nil` but you're trying to add the **name** which causes the error.

Some suggestions:

`fetch(context:` returns always an array of the `NSManagedObject` subclass so cast it immediately.

Since you are using `NSManagedObject` subclass get the `name` property directly rather than with `valueForKey`.

The check for > 0 is not needed because the loop will be skipped in case of an empty array.

```
  let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [Task]
  // check data existance
  print(results.count)

  for task in results {
     if let expName = task.name {
        print("expence name is :", expName)
        tasks += task      
        print("my array is : \(tasks)")
     }
  }
```

or shorter

```
 let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [Task]
 tasks.filter{ $0.name != nil  }
```

The most efficient way is to filter the tasks **before** the fetch via an appropriate predicate.

Comment: Isn't `Task` the `NSManagedObject` subclass?